# jquery :- get div element html

Tags: jquery

```
    <div id="id1" class="desc">Hello World 1</div>
    <div id="id2" class="desc">Hello World 2</div>
    <div>test</div>
```

In document.ready,

```
$(function(){   
   var $dvObj = $('div.desc');   
   alert($dvObj[0]); 
   alert($dvObj[0].text());  //Nothing comes up
   alert($dvObj[0].html());  //Nothing comes up
});
```

I am not able to get the div html. Pls suggest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use square brackets to access an element of a jQuery object you get the actual DOM element, not a jQuery object. DOM nodes don't have a `text` or `html` method.

You can use the [`eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) method to get a jQuery object containing the element at the specified index:

```
$(function(){ 
    var $dvObj = $('div.desc');
    alert($dvObj.eq(0)); 
    alert($dvObj.eq(0).text());
    alert($dvObj.eq(0).html());
});
```